# Switching between fragments in same container

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have two buttons in my Activity. When I click on button1, I display a fragment and when I click on button2, I display another fragment in the same container. For each fragment I am setting a tag so that if the button is clicked again, I will just replace the fragment in the container. The problem is when i click again on the second button, the findFragmentByTag returns 'null' and the fragment is loaded again. 
Here is the code I am using

```
    Button button1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("button1");
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            if(myFragment==null){
                MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, "button1");                   
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }else{                  
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, myFragment, "button1");                 
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }

        }
    });
    Button button2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("button2");// always return null
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            if(myFragment==null){
                MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, "button2");                   
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }else{
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, myFragment, "button2");                 
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        }
    });
```

In the above code **fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("button2")** always return null.
Can anyone please let me know how to get this working. I have seen other threads, but could not find any solution.

TIA,
VijayRaj

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute pending transactions before you call a new one. Try this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()
```

**Edit**

After replacing a Fragment with FragmentTransaction, you have to **add it to the backstack.**

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(button1);
```

Comment: I added this before calling **fragmentManager.beginTransaction()** but still it doesn't work

Comment: Ah I see it now, you dont send the Transaction **addToBackStack(button1)** after replacing.  Cheers!

Comment: where should I add it to the backstack?? In my onclicklistener of button1 or button2 ??

Comment: For every. I have updated my awnser, explaining it in general, if you replace a Fragment you have to add it to the backstack, this means for every transaction replacement you have to add the replaced fragment to the backstack.

Comment: when I use addToBackStack(button1), the whole fragment is loaded again....is it possible to get the previous fragment again?

Comment: If you want to get the previous fragment back, use fragmentTransaction.popBackStack();

Comment: addtoBackStack is not what I was looking for....I am using hide and show method of fragmentTransaction to switch between two fragments